Apache Camel route with multipart/form-data content type payload overwritten
I have a camel route that consumes multipart/form-data content type and produces the same. The data consists of a file with the name of "content" and a json called "metadata" that is metadata about the file being uploaded.
The route manipulates the metadata json only.
My problem is that the payload is being overwritten all the time by the end of the route with the response code 201 and the original metadata json.
I had to add exception handling in a try-catch block as otherwise the OnException() results would be executed but still overwritten.
My custom error handling is now sorted but when the route successfully executes (I can see the result in the target application) the response will be still 201 with the original json as the body.
This has definitely to do with .unmarshal().mimeMultipart().split().body() line as I tested with outputs before and after.
Here is my route:
 public void configure() throws Exception {
    onException(Exception.class)
            .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, constant(Constants.CODE_400))
            .unmarshal().json()
            .process(new Processor() {
                @Override
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {

                    final Throwable ex = exchange.getProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT, Throwable.class);
                    exchange.getIn().setBody("{" + ex.getMessage() + "}");
                }
            })
            .handled(true);

    JacksonDataFormat metadataFormat = new JacksonDataFormat(Document.class);
    rest("/documents_ext")
            .post()
            .type(Document.class)
            .consumes(Constants.FORM_DATA_CONTENT_TYPE)
            .produces(FORM_DATA_CONTENT_TYPE)
            .param()
            .name(Constants.BODY)
            .required(true)
            .type(RestParamType.body)
            .endParam()
            .to(Constants.DIRECT_DOCUMENT);
    from(Constants.DIRECT_DOCUMENT)
            .routeId(DocumentsRestRoute.class.getName())
            .process(new GeneralLoggingProcessor(DOCUMENTS_REST_ROUTE_EVENT, "IG rest endpoint for new incoming document called"))
            .doTry()
                .unmarshal().mimeMultipart().split().body()
                .process(this::processIncomingPayload)
                .unmarshal(metadataFormat)
                .process(this::processDocument)
                .process(new GeneralLoggingProcessor(DOCUMENTS_REST_ROUTE_EVENT, "Authenticating in Claim Center"))
                .process(new ClaimCenterAuthenticationProcessor(insuranceSuiteProperties))
                .setHeader(Constants.Content_Type_HEADER, constant(Constants.FORM_DATA_CONTENT_TYPE))
                .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, HttpMethods.POST)
                .setHeader("responseTimeout", () -> getCamelContext().getPropertiesComponent()
                    .resolveProperty("acc.document_transfer_timeout").get())
                .toD(buildHttpCCUri(insuranceSuiteProperties, DOCUMENTS_URI) + "&httpClient.responseTimeout=${header.responseTimeout}")
            .choice()
            .when(exchange -> (Integer)(exchange.getIn().getHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE)) == 201)
            .process(exchange -> exchange.getIn().setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, 201))
            .process(exchange -> {
                var payloadMapper = new ObjectMapper();
                ObjectNode documentNode = payloadMapper.createObjectNode();
                String documentId = new ObjectMapper().readTree(exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class)).get("data").get("attributes").get("id").asText();
                //todo add document id to be returned
                documentNode.put("documentId", documentId);
                exchange.getIn().setBody(payloadMapper.writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(documentNode));
            })
            .end()
            .endDoTry()
            .doCatch(Exception.class)
            .process(exchange -> {
                exchange.getIn().setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE, 400);
                final Throwable ex = exchange.getProperty(Exchange.EXCEPTION_CAUGHT, Throwable.class);
                if(ex instanceof HttpOperationFailedException){
                    exchange.getIn().setBody("{" + ((HttpOperationFailedException) ex).getResponseBody() + "}");
                }
                else {
                    exchange.getIn().setBody("{" + ex.getMessage() + "}");
                }
            })
            .end()
            .stop();
}

As you can see my last action is to overwrite the response but I'll still see this in postman:

Any help is appreciated!
